# How to get unique values in a column using excel formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have Excel Data like below

```
       JID     Val

       1001    22
       1030    6
       1031    14          
       1041    8
       1001    3
       2344    8
       1030    8
       2344    6
       1041    8
```

How do i get the unique JID values like below using formula?

```
UJID   

1001
1030
1031
1041    
2344
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the remove duplicate function

Select the column range

Go to `Data` Tab

then click on `Remove Duplicates`

Comment: Is this the correct answer? The title says "using formula", which this answer doesn't do.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a solution to get a list of unique items from your tables

There is two parts to this solution.

Part 1) Unique Count

> {=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$10<>"",MATCH($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),1))}

This will count the number of unique items in your data table and will ignore any blanks

*Note this is an array formula and you will need to use "Ctrl" + "Shift" + "Enter" to use

Part 2) Unique List

This formula will give you the list of unique items in your table

> ={IF(ROWS($E$5:E5)>$E$2,"",INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$10<>"",MATCH($A$2:$A$10,$A$2:$A$10,0)),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW($A$2:$A$10)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS($E$5:E5))))}

again this is an array formula. You can then drag this formula down to get all the unique items.

This formula is a dynamic formula, meaning you can set the data range past your current data range and the list will update as you enter new values.

*Here is a great video to watch to understand this further

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3u8VHTvSNE4

[image]

Comment: not sure why this is down voted, this seems to perfectly answer the question

Answer (score 9):

[image: Select distinct values]

I think I've found a more elegant workaround without array-functions or built-in functions:

- 1<sup>st</sup> column (ID): 
  `this is the array from we'd like to select distinct values`
- 2<sup>nd</sup> column (criteria):
  checks whether this is the first occurrence 
  `=IF((ROW()-1)=MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$500,0),1,0)`
- 3<sup>rd</sup> column (cumulative):
  `=SUM($B$2:B2)`
- 4<sup>th</sup> column (count):
  `this is constant 1`
- 5<sup>th</sup> column (unique ID):
  `=OFFSET($A$2,MATCH(ROW()-1,$C$2:$C$501,0)-1,)`
- 6<sup>th</sup> column (count):
  `=SUMIF(A2:A21,F2,D2:D21)`

Comment: Nice! Very logical.