# How to find out unique value in a column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In a column there is huge data. Like 250,1250,2250...

Now I need to find out if there are any duplicates in the column.

When I try to applying remove duplicates or data analysis inbuilt function of Excel. Entire column is getting highlighted with red. Because it is considering 250 and 1250 as duplicate.

Is there a way to find out the unique values of a column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get unique values in a column using excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145924/how-to-get-unique-values-in-a-column-using-excel-formula)

Comment: `250` and `1250` are not duplicates.  But when you select the option to `Remove Duplicates`, it WILL highlight the entire column when the `Dialog Box` opens.  But then, when you hit `OK` it should only remove the actual duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you have several ways to filter for unique values or remove duplicate values:

- To filter for unique values, use the Advanced command in the Sort &
  Filter group on the Data tab.
- To remove duplicate values, use the Remove Duplicates command in the
  Data Tools group on the Data tab.
- To highlight unique or duplicate values, use the Conditional
  Formatting command in the Style group on the Home tab.

Answer (score 0):

copy the column onto a new sheet and remove duplicates. that will give you a list of unique values. use countif against each value and the original columns. sort that descending.